# Add time stamp using formula on flow

Tags: visual-workflow

in a formula can we also add a timestamp so we have date then time as well?

so when I use this
`TEXT(HOUR(Today()))`

I get

> The formula expression is invalid: Function HOUR may not be used in this type of formula

Answer (score 0):

I found that the function

```
TEXT(NOW())
```

will post the date and time

This however will be in the US format. There is also a "Z" appended when using the now function.

just to edit this. I managed to find a way of changing the date into uk format - fyi the format function doesn't work in a flow. So i did the following.

```
TEXT(DAY(Today())) + "-" + TEXT(MONTH(Today())) + "-" + TEXT(YEAR(Today())) + " " +
RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(NOW()), "Z", ""), 8)
```

- used the right function to clear the date as it was in US format and substitute to hide the "Z" then used the day/month/year functions to display in UK format instead of US.

The output went from:
`2023-01-31 18:14:46Z`

to:
`31-1-2023 19:02:54`

Comment: wouldn't UK format be `31-01-2023 19:02:54` (leading zeroes)?

Comment: you're right. I thought about doing a RIGHT then add a 0 in front of month 

RIGHT("0" & TEXT(MONTH(Today())), 2)

but this would also append in front of November & December so it would potentially look like this
30-011-2023 19:02:54
30-012-2023 19:02:54

so i left it as is

Comment: you just need to make the formula smarter to look at the value of MONTH(TODAY()) and if 10-12, don't prepend `0`

Comment: will take this into account, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

I created a Constant resource as a text field and enter a default  value. Then, I used the formula:  DATETIMEVALUE(TEXT(TODAY()) & " Default value ").

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged because it adds an extra step to actually get to the information, and because links tend to become unavailable as time goes on. Salesforce in particular has a bad habit of making existing links invalid every few years (when they decide to re-invent their URI scheme and/or refresh the site design). You should [edit] your answer to include the parts of that link that are relevent to the question.

Comment: is there any way of incorporating this into the current formula that I already have?

Left($User.FirstName,1) + Left($User.LastName,1) + " " + TEXT(MONTH(Today())) + "/" +TEXT(DAY(Today())) + "/" + TEXT(YEAR(Today()))

If I append this I'll get an error.